# PHP FFMPEG not working

Tags: php

https://github.com/PHP-FFMpeg/PHP-FFMpeg

I got this from GitHub, and I included the code (at least I thought I did).

`require_once '/FFMpeg/FFProbe.php';
require_once '/FFMpeg/FFMpeg.php';`

And the code returns with this weird error that I cannot seem to find a solution to on their GitHub Repo page.

`Fatal error: Class 'Doctrine\Common\Cache\ArrayCache' not found in /FFMpeg/FFProbe.php on line 204`

Any reason why this error occurs or am I stupid?

**EDIT #1:**
It occurs when I use this code that they supplied on their GitHub

    `$ffmpeg = FFMpeg\FFMpeg::create();
    $video = $ffmpeg->open('video.mpg');
    $video
    ->filters()
    ->resize(new FFMpeg\Coordinate\Dimension(320, 240))
    ->synchronize();
    $video
    ->frame(FFMpeg\Coordinate\TimeCode::fromSeconds(10))
    ->save('frame.jpg');
    $video
    ->save(new FFMpeg\Format\Video\X264(), 'export-x264.mp4')
    ->save(new FFMpeg\Format\Video\WMV(), 'export-wmv.wmv')
    ->save(new FFMpeg\Format\Video\WebM(), 'export-webm.webm');`

Comment: Check `ArrayCache` class is present at location 'Doctrine\Common\Cache\

Comment: There is no location named that, and on their GitHub you don't see it there as well.  I also edited the page with more info.

Comment: Did you use composer, to install dependencies?

Comment: Nope, I just downloaded the folder "src". I don't really understand the point of Composer at the moment.

Comment: Check in `FFProbe` is there is statement like `use ArrayCache` it means that te FFProbe code needs the `ArrayCache class` but it is not found. That means the `ArrayCache.php` file has been not auto loaded or included properly.

Comment: `$cache = new ArrayCache();` That's the line that the error shows, and on the top it shows this. `use Doctrine\Common\Cache\ArrayCache;
use Doctrine\Common\Cache\Cache;`

Comment: This library will not work without installing it and its dependencies either manually or (preferred way) using composer https://getcomposer.org/

Comment: That's kind of stupid in my opinion, that sounds like a waste of space to me :/

Comment: There must be a way to get it manually?

Comment: There sure is, you just need to check the documentation for required dependencies and download them all; if the docs do not state dependencies, you'll need to check the code itself.

Answer (score 0):

You must run composer `path/to/composer.phar install` (or if global install `composer install`) to get all dependencies.

You can download composer from [here](https://getcomposer.org/download/)